# Google Plusone count

Tags: https, google-plus-one

Im getting different counts for google PlusOne for https and http protocols.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour and have any suggestions as to resolve it.

I am using the typical implementation shown [here](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/).

I also found [this](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url) link regarding canonical urls but I dont think this is relevant in this case as I have no alternative canonical url only repeated content served on the 2 different protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages referred by different URLs are *different*. One can serve different content via HTTP and HTTPS. So if you want to have the same counter, you need to specify the canonical URL (with or without https, you decide) in counter parameters.

Comment: I realise content on different protocols are different was querying whether I could specify a url with the google plus button and it looks as if the canonical url can be used for this purpose. My solution however was to force the page to render as http as this was causing other issues anyway. thanks